# Can a Cassandra non-superuser create keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra, permissions, datastax

I'm trying to find any documentation which would state the permission needed to create a new keyspace. I would assume ONLY a role with superuser = true is allowed to create new Keyspaces?

We would like to limit access so one user can not see other keyspaces but still be able to create new keyspaces.

What's the best approach here?

1. Superuser = true but limit only to keyspaces created by itself or granted
2. non-super user with keyspace creation privileges.

Not sure if any of these 2 points above is possible.
Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first scenario isn't possible.  A super user is a user that *cannot* be limited.

The second one though, sort of is:

```
GRANT CREATE
ON ALL KEYSPACES
TO keyspace_creator;
```

Granting `CREATE` permissions on `ALL KEYSPACES` is the only way to grant keyspace creation.  Just remember that it also grants *table* creation (within *ALL* keyspaces), as well as `SELECT` and `MODIFY` on tables they have created.

They can still "see" and describe other keyspaces and tables.  But that user *cannot* access (`SELECT`) any tables that they have not been explicitly granted access to or did not create themselves.